# Can I set different titles from names of upsell products?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, import, csv, up-sells

Can I set alternative names in upsell products list?

[image]

I would like to set an attribute "upsell_name" in CSV import so labels in red circles would be altered.

For example for product "Long name param1 param2", I would set "upsell_name" to "param1 param2".

Comment: Can you please give some feedback? Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extension with this code and adjust `$product->setName(....)` to your needs:

> app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_upsell>
                <observers>
                    <set_upsell_names>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>changeUpsellNames</method>
                    </set_upsell_names>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_upsell>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function changeUpsellNames(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($collection = $observer->getCollection()) {
            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                $product->setName($product->getData('upsell_name'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```